# Error in code - producing same result

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that I do not fully understand.  It is producing the same result.

The first section ('Return all the Account numbers that are greater than 250 days) works perfectly.  It take all the account numbers where the last payment date is greater than 250 days and returns the account numbers and corresponding days on to a new worksheet.

I need the next two sections (Return all the Account numbers that are 68 and older) and (Return all the Account numbers that are younger than 18), to return the account numbers where the age of the account holder is greater and equal to 68 , and those that are younger than 18.

This code is producing the same result for the 3 sections.  The page that the code is taking from, the columns used are ('A' account number, 'E' Days since last payment DSLP, and, 'C' Age)

Thanks in advance

```
'Populate the Recourse Items Sheet to provide the list of items for recourse

Dim DSLP As Range
Dim NewRange As Range
Dim MyCount As Long
MyCount = 1
Dim NewRange2 As Range
Dim MyCount2 As Long
MyCount2 = 1

'Return all the Account numbers that are greater than 250 days

    For Each DSLP In SFS.Range("E2:E" & LastRow)

        Select Case DSLP.Value

            Case Is > 250

                If MyCount = 1 Then
                    Set NewRange = DSLP.Offset(0, -4)

                Else
                   Set NewRange = Application.Union(NewRange, DSLP.Offset(0, -4))

                End If

               MyCount = MyCount + 1

'Return the corresponding days past 250

                If MyCount2 = 1 Then
                    Set NewRange2 = DSLP.Offset(0, -0)

                Else
                   Set NewRange2 = Application.Union(NewRange2, DSLP.Offset(0, -0))

                End If

               MyCount2 = MyCount2 + 1

        End Select

    Next DSLP

'Copy NewRange from inactive sheet into active sheet
 NewRange.Copy Destination:=RI.Range("A4")
 NewRange2.Copy Destination:=RI.Range("B4")

 Dim OLD As Range
 Dim NewRange3 As Range
 Dim MyCount3 As Long
 MyCount3 = 1
 Dim NewRange4 As Range
 Dim MyCount4 As Long
 MyCount4 = 1

'Return all the Account numbers that are 68 and older

    For Each OLD In SFS.Range("C2:C" & LastRow)

        Select Case OLD.Value

            Case Is >= 68

                If MyCount3 = 1 Then
                    Set NewRange3 = OLD.Offset(0, -2)

                Else
                   Set NewRange3 = Application.Union(NewRange3, OLD.Offset(0, -2))

                End If

               MyCount3 = MyCount3 + 1

'Return the corresponding ages 68 and older

                If MyCount4 = 1 Then
                    Set NewRange4 = OLD.Offset(0, -0)

                Else
                   Set NewRange4 = Application.Union(NewRange4, OLD.Offset(0, -0))

                End If

               MyCount4 = MyCount4 + 1

        End Select

    Next OLD

'Copy NewRange from inactive sheet into active sheet
    NewRange.Copy Destination:=RI.Range("D4")
    NewRange2.Copy Destination:=RI.Range("E4")

 Dim YOUNG As Range
 Dim NewRange5 As Range
 Dim MyCount5 As Long
 MyCount5 = 1
 Dim NewRange6 As Range
 Dim MyCount6 As Long
 MyCount6 = 1

'Return all the Account numbers that are younger than 18

    For Each YOUNG In SFS.Range("C2:C" & LastRow)

        Select Case YOUNG.Value

            Case Is < 18

                If MyCount5 = 1 Then
                    Set NewRange5 = YOUNG.Offset(0, -2)

                Else
                   Set NewRange5 = Application.Union(NewRange5, YOUNG.Offset(0, -2))

                End If

               MyCount5 = MyCount5 + 1

'Return the corresponding ages younger than 18

                If MyCount6 = 1 Then
                    Set NewRange6 = cell.Offset(0, -0)

                Else
                   Set NewRange4 = Application.Union(NewRange6, cell.Offset(0, -0))

                End If

               MyCount6 = MyCount6 + 1

        End Select

    Next YOUNG

'Copy NewRange from inactive sheet into active sheet
    NewRange.Copy Destination:=RI.Range("G4")
    NewRange2.Copy Destination:=RI.Range("H4")
```

Comment: Use the debugger and step through the code to see what's not working as expected.

Comment: Why do you copy `NewRange` and `NewRange2` even after setting up `NewRange3` / `NewRange4` and `NewRange5` / `NewRange6`

Comment: What is the point of providing you with more code that you *'do not fully understand'*?

Comment: Hi Jeeped, I was hoping that this is a supportive community, where people are trying to learn, others could assist in that learning.

Comment: Hi YowE3K, Ahh, I see what you mean, I forgot to change the that to the new range.  After I changed that, I have now got an error (Object Variable or with Block not set)

Comment: Recommend that you add Option Explicit to the top of your module and get all of your variables properly declared.

Comment: `Set NewRange4 = Application.Union(NewRange6, cell.Offset(0, -0))` isn't going to help either.

Comment: I'm afraid that saying "I have now got an error (Object Variable or with Block not set)" isn't really helpful - you have a lot of code there and it is **very** useful if you tell us which line is causing the issue.

Comment: `Set NewRange6 = cell.Offset(0, -0)` isn't going to work very well either.  (And `.Offset(0, -0)` on any range is pointless!  `x.Offset(0, 0)` is equivalent to `x`.)

Comment: What I find strange is that the last two errors I noticed would have caused your code to crash **before** it incorrectly produced the same results for the third section.  Perhaps you don't have any data where the person is less than 18.

Comment: Thanks YowE3K, you are being really helpful.  I have fixed up the errors that you have spotted and it is working smoothly when I have an account where there is an account holder younger than 18 and 68 or over.  The trouble is where there is no data there and it has nothing to copy in to the new range.  The code 'Copy NewRange from inactive sheet into active sheet
        NewRange3.Copy Destination:=RI.Range("D4")
        NewRange4.Copy Destination:=RI.Range("E4") Errors at the first line as there is no data

Comment: the reason that you are having trouble, is that you did not think this through completely. instead of duplicating all the code three times, you should have added two more `case` sections to the original code.

Comment: think of it like a bag of colored marbles ... you are allowed to take out only one at a time, and you have to put it back if it is the wrong one ... first task is to put all the red ones in a bowl (that is your first program)... second task, you have 3 bowls and you have to put all green marbles in first bowl, blue in second bowl, yellow in third bowl.  .... you would not do the process that was used for the red marbles 3 times in sequence ... you would put the marbles into one of the three bowls as you took them out of the bag, and only returned colors that were not one of the three

Comment: Thats a good way of looking at it.  I can try and merge the code together, I did think that there must be a way to shorten it but with my limited VBA, I opted to just get to to work the way I could.  I will give it a go, by added in in extra cases, Thanks :)